# What events are fired while model changes in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Help me please... I try this:

```
model.bind 'all', this.console, this
```

And when I change something inside of model I have double-firing of my handler.

But when I changed event for binding:

```
model.bind 'change', this.console, this
```

Everything is ok. Why? What is nature of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single change to the model's **`a`** attribute will trigger two events:

- `change`
- `change:a`

and [binding to `all`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-on) means that your event handler will get called for both of them:

> Callbacks bound to the special `"all"` event will be triggered when any event occurs, and are passed the name of the event as the first argument.

If you only bind to the `change` event, the your handler will only get called for the overall "part of the model changed" event and you won't see the `change:a` that is specific to the change on just that attribute.

For example, given this:

```
class M extends Backbone.Model

m = new M
m.on 'all', (ev) -> console.log ev
m.set a: 'b'
```

You'll get `change` and `change:a` in the console.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yRDjd/

But if you do this:

```
class M extends Backbone.Model

m = new M
m.on 'change',   -> console.log 'the model changed'
m.on 'change:a', -> console.log 'a changed'
m.set a: 'b'
```

you'll see separate messages for each `change` event.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wnmXe/

Comment: Incredible answer, as usual. Thanks!